# Smoke renders only on CPU (Cycles)

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation, gpu

First things first

> version: 2.93.3, branch: master, commit date: 2021-08-17 18:30,  hash:
> 8b80d19f3641, type: release build date: 2021-08-17, 23:47:11 platform:
> Windows,
> Graphics Card: 5700 XT, Driver Version: 21.8.2,
> CPU: AMD R5 3600

Hey there, I'm fairly new to Blender and making my throught some tutorials whatsoever. I tried to add smoke (good ol' Cups and Donuts) but it did not work, as soon as im switching to render view (**Cycles**).

**BUT** as soon as i switch from *GPU-Compute* to *CPU* without touching any other settings, it works, it renders, it gets animated. So I made a complete new scene, just adding a background plane and the smoke domain + flow object, as you can see below, rendering on the CPU worked, on GPU it did not.

[image: Smoke rendered on CPU]
CPU-rendered

[image: Smoke not rendered on GPU]
GPU-rendered

Am i missing anything, or doing anything wrong (even tho I did not touch any settings inbetween)?

On a sidenote and for my own curiosity: I saw, that rendering with my GPU would hook around 4 Gbyte of Video-Memory, for the scene above, and on CPU only around 3 Mbyte of RAM. Is that something to worry about, or is that normal? Time wise, they were comparable for that scene with around 90 seconds.

Best regards and many thanks in advance! If you need additional infos, hook me up with what you need.
Phil

Edit: I updated the graphic cards driver and tried to switch to *Feature Set: Experimental*.

Comment: Is your graphics card AMD?

Comment: Yes, it's an AMD 5700 XT.

Comment: AMD and Blender do not speak the same language natively right now, so check your drivers, and if no go, report this as a bug.